# Change Name of Apple Developer Profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I took over the Apple Developer Account of my father yesterday, but I really don't know how to change it to have my name displayed in the Member Center and iTunes Connect.

Comment: Try asking in the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: I'm going to create an iOS developer account during the next few months, and I'm 17, based on your experience, can I create an account with my father's credit card and change its name to my name? Who should I contact (which email address?) and What should I say to them to change the name of my developer account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happened to me as well, I purchased a developer account for my brother a couple months ago and he eventually decided that he didn't want to put the effort in. At this point I contacted Apple both by email and phone and they explained to me that it was not possible to transfer the account to my name (a single developer can not have more than one account).

After that I decided to offer the account to a friend who had an interest in learning cocoa and repeated the process of contacting Apple only to find that "limit 1 per dev" rule wasn't the only reason I couldn't transfer the account... Basically they told me I was out of luck.

Once a developer account has been created the **only** way you can change the name on the account is if you migrate it from being a personal account to a business account.

Sorry to say it but you're sitting on a $99 dud account. (I'm right there with you)

Comment: Well, the problem is it was something like a birthday present for me, and the account has the fully 99$ paid with his credit card, and thats the problem - apple takes the name of who paid the account - the iTunes Account was mine - registered on my name and stuff, but it was his credit card what made the name for the developer account thing, this is very annoying because I want to develop under my name, not my fathers... 99$ paid for develop under a "false" name -.-

Comment: @MauriceA. I see in your profile you're 15 years old, if that is accurate you would need to develop under your fathers name and make sure he's aware that Apple doesn't take taxes out of your cut and you are responsible for paying the every April. Apple does not allow developers under 18.

Comment: Hey there, i mailed Apple and they changed the name, they said that is no problem, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1):

You can contact Apple developer support for these kind of things. They will help you.

Comment: No they wont, they are inflexible and don't provide a good collaborative business model.  It's either like the way we do it or go elsewhere.  Shocking support for developers.